# How to make a combobox, inside a jtree, show its menu?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtree

I basically have a JTree where I show certain information. In one of the "sub-trees" I got a panel which consists of a panel with GridLayout(0,2) and a JPanel as well as a combobox.

I've noticed that no components in my tree react on input. This of course means that my combobox won't react when I try to click on it. I tried to implement a default cell editor, which worked but not like I wanted to. It basically opened the menu but when I selected one of the items it replaced the JLabel so only the combobox was visible.

**Pictures**

Before clicking on the box [image]

After clicking on the box [image]

Code that I tried with

```
 TreeCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(blockedAlternatives);
                infoTree.setEditable(true);
                infoTree.setCellEditor(editor);
```

I obviously don't want to be able to edit the whole tree, I just want to be able to show the combobox's menu. I just took this code from the web for testing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It basically opened the menu but when I selected one of the items it
>   replaced the JLabel so only the combobox was visible.

Well that is what you'd excpect as thats how the `DefaultCellEditor(JComboBox jcb)` is meant to be:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor;

    public class TreeEditJComboBox {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            JTree tree = new JTree(props);


            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"A", "B", "C"});
            TreeCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);

            tree.setEditable(true);
            tree.setCellEditor(editor);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
            frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(300, 150);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
}
```

You could try making your own `DefaultCellEditor` and override `getTableCellEditorComponent()` and then return a `JPanel` which holds the `JLabel` and `JComboBox`, something like:

```
class MyDefaultCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

public MyDefaultCellEditor(JComboBox comboBox) {
    super(comboBox);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
   //return custom coponent
    return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
}
}
```

then:

```
 TreeCellEditor editor = new MyDefaultCellEditor(blockedAlternatives);
```

you may have to override a few other methods too. I was just showing the logic

**References:**

- [Creating a DefaultCellEditor: JComboBox](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingaDefaultCellEditorJComboBox.htm)
- [extends DefaultCellEditor](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/extendsDefaultCellEditor.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although I went with another design this was a good answer and will be helpful to me, and others, in the future.
Cheers.